# Log4j 2 builder getting overriden

Tags: java, log4j2

I've been trying to replace old .xml files for Log4j 2 for some time now but can't get it to work.

My biggest issue is that loggers I add for packages are completely ignored.

```
builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.reflections", Level.INFO));
```

This should mean that Debugs are ignored but I can see, for example, this in my console:

```
2017-12-01 02:16:45,523 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file
```

This doesn't follow the PatternLayout I've created either which leads me to believe that somehow Log4j 2 is being ignored by the loggers in Reflections.

The odd thing is that I'm doing the exact same thing in the builder API as I did in the .xml file...

Anyone got a clue how I can remedy this?

Comment: There really isn't enough information provided here to say for sure, it could be any number of reasons. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a couple of more hours I managed to figure it out.
So the issue was two parts.

1. I had a dependency that used a slfj4 bidning for log4j, not log4j2, so I excluded that and replaced it with log4j2s implementation for slf4j and that solved the oddly formatted logs since they were now going to the right place.
   Why that didn't work from the beginning, since I have the bridge from log4j to log4j2 as a dependency I haven't figured out yet.
2. The second problem was that my custom ConfigurationFactory for log4j2 would randomly stop finding my custom appender. After a lot of googling i finally found [THIS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Using+Custom+Log4J2+Appender) which under step 3 adds the package where their appender was stored in the log4j2.xml. So with this in mind i found that there is a method called `setPackages()` in log4j2s builder. And now it appears to be working consistently.